# Extracting (approximate) data from a PostScript file containing plot generated by gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, postscript

Suppose that I have a PostScript file containing a plot which was generated using gnuplot.  However, I do not have the source data, nor do I have the gnuplot commands that were used to generate the plot.

Do you know of any way to somehow extract data from a graphic representation (i.e., a PostScript file)?  Such code would have to literally "read off of the graph" (in particular, I have a smoothed line/scatter XY plot) from the pixel representation, and I know that the results would be approximate at best (but this would still be very highly desirable).

Do you have any experience with this?  Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's really a shame that gnuplot changes the coordinates when it could use the original values adding a simple transformation in the PostScript code. I guess it's so for uniformity with other drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostScript is nothing but a programming language to describe pages. A PostScript file is a plain text file containing a program that descbrise a page which gets interpreted by a printer or viewer.

As such it is amendable to programmatic manipulation, albeit in a low-level way.

I would approach this task in the following way.

1. Learn PostScript. (The [reference manual](https://www.google.com/search?q=postscript%20reference%20manual&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) will come in handy.)
2. Study the output from gnuplot. How does the gnuplot outputs the graph? Is this systematic? etcetera.
3. Parse and extract the needed information.

Comment: PostScript is even **more** than '*nothing but* a programming language to describe pages'. It's even a Turing-complete programming language (in other words: it can do *everything*, not just describe pages). And now something for Young Grashoppers to think long about: *How easy is it in your experience to take the program code of any **other** language and manipulate it programmatically so that it still is functional?!?!* -- So while it may be possible, it could turn out to be a really daunting task. Depends on the real-world PS code which you may need to manipulate...

Comment: The postscript generated by the gnuplot driver is clean/simple enough that anyone with even a little programming knowlege should be able to handle this without really learning postscipt to any depth.  If there is interest I could post a few pointers, but seeing as this is an old question I wont take the time if there is no interest.

Answer (score 0):

`g3data`, available [here](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php/), looks like a possibility.  It runs on Linux.